# Converge columns in dataframe to single column in specific order

Tags: python-3.x

Python newb here, I have two columns in a data frame, we'll call them dat1 and dat2

```
    dat1  dat2
0   123   20
1   456   30
2   789   10
3   123   10
4   456   20
5   789   30
```

I need to convert that into a single column like so:

```
10   
789
123
20
123
456
30
456
789
```

or in terms of columns, [dat2,dat1,dat1,dat2,dat1,dat1,dat2,dat1,dat1]
I made up this terrible code:

```
unique = dp['dat2'].unique()
for each in unique:
    mylist.append(each)
    for x in dp:
        mylist.append(dp[dp['dat2'] == each])
```

and i get the output as below

```
20
  dat1  dat2
0  123    20
4  456    20
  dat1  dat2
0  123    20
4  456    20
30
  dat1  dat2
1  456    30
5  789    30
  dat1  dat2
1  456    30
5  789    30
10
  dat1  dat2
2  789    10
3  123    10
  dat1  dat2
2  789    10
3  123    10
```

I'm basically trying to replicate the function of the pivot table in excel. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# sort the values by the second column
dp = dp.sort_values(by='dat2')


# create a list which will collect the results
my_data = []

# loop over the 2nd unique columns values
for d2 in dp.dat2.unique():
    # insert the data into the list
    my_data.append(d2)

    # grep the dat1 data from the table, where dat2 == d2
    for i in dp.dat1[dp.dat2 == d2]:
        my_data.append(i)


my_data
[10, 789, 123, 20, 123, 456, 30, 456, 789]
```

Answer (score 0):

using pd.concat you can concat the dataframe data

```
import pandas as pd
df={'id1':[11,22,33],'id2':[77,88,99]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
print(pd.concat([df['id1'],df['id2']]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are grouping the values based on column dat2 and adding elements from dat1 after each dat2 element, I would use pd.groupby

```
import pandas as pd

dat1 = [123,456,789,123,456,789]
dat2 = [20,30,10,10,20,30]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dat1, dat2)), columns=['dat1', 'dat2'])

grouped = df.groupby(['dat2']).agg({'dat1':list}).reset_index()
dict_list = grouped.to_dict('records')
new_data_list = []
for single_dict in dict_list:
    new_data_list.append(single_dict['dat2'])
    new_data_list += single_dict['dat1']
print(new_data_list)
```

result:

```
[10, 789, 123, 20, 123, 456, 30, 456, 789]
```